# How to export several SQL results into an Excel workbook with Python?

Tags: python, sql-server, excel, python-3.x, openpyxl

Currently I am able to connect to a SQL server, fetch data through the tables and export the results in a .xlsx file, but I am able to export only one set of results instead of the two set of results that SQL displays in Microsoft SQL Server.

This is the set of results that I receive from SQL.

[image: Two sets of results]

This is my Python code that I use to connect to the database, extract results and save them in an Excel file.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
from datetime import timedelta, date
import pypyodbc

def extract_from_databases():

    # declare cursors for the rows of the .xlsx file
    # in openpyxl, you start counting from row 1 and row 1 contains the headers
    row_main_file = 2

    #set the start date of yesterday
    start_date = date.today() - timedelta(days=1)

    # declare the SPs
    retrieve_values = "[MSA].[CSchema].[DEV_N2G_GetData_ResultsExport] @start_date='{start_date:%Y-%m-%d}'".format(
    start_date=start_date)

    #connect to the database
    database_connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}",
    server="10.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="xxxx", pwd="xxxxx", Trusted_Connection="No")


    #declare main cursor in SQL
    main_cursor = main_connection.cursor()

    print("The execution of SPs is in process")
    main_cursor.execute(retrieve_values)
    main_cursor_results = main_cursor.fetchall()

    c_wb = Workbook()
    c_s =  c_wb.active
    c_s.title = "Data Sheet 1"
    c_s['A1'] = "Date"
    c_s['B1'] = 'hour'
    c_s['C1'] = 'CName'
    c_s['D1'] = 'SName'
    c_s['E1'] = 'SCname'
    c_s['F1'] = 'CS_I'
    c_s['G1'] = 'CS_D'
    c_s['H1'] = 'PS_I'
    c_s['I1'] = 'PS_D'

    for index, value in enumerate(main_cursor_results):
        try:
            # extract from the tuple 'results' the value of each item and store it in every column for all rows
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=1).value = value[0]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=2).value = value[1]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=3).value = value[2]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=4).value = value[3]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=5).value = value[4]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=6).value = value[5]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=7).value = value[6]
            c_s.cell(row=row_main_file, column=8).value = value[7]
        except:
            print("Error in line %s\n data=%s" % (index, value))
        row_main_file = row_main_file + 1
    c_wb.save("C:\\Users\\xxx\\outputs\\Workbooks\\export_results.xlsx")
    print("The writing process for the values.")
    colombia_cursor.close()
```

How can I export the two sets of results from SQL in two worksheets?

Comment: What does ```main_cursor.fetchall()``` return? Can you print it to see if everything is there?

Comment: main_cursor.fetchall() returns all the rows from the SP but only the results from the first set of results, the other set of results does not appear.

Comment: Does the SP have two queries? Can you change the SP or add new SP's?  Is your question - ```My stored procedure has two queries, how do I *capture* the results from both queries?```

Comment: Just going to attach the results of the main_cursor_fetchall(). Yes, my stored procedure has two queries and I want to capture the results from both queries. I am not able to modify the SP.

Comment: Found out that main_cursor_fetchall() got the results from the first query but it does not show the results of the second query.

Comment: [This example](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/python/examples/CallSPMultiResultSet.html) shows the stored procedure being called twice, once for the first query and again for the second. - If that works you should post it as an answer. - my bad ```if cursor.nextset()==True:   for rec in cursor:...```

Comment: [pyodbc return multiple cursors from stored procedure...](https://stackoverflow.com/q/273203/2823755)

Comment: And it just worked smoothly!