# Is there a way to get the full output of SQL-server's sp_help in django?

Tags: python, sql-server, django

SQL server has the prompt:  sp_help table_name.

I would like to access the output of this using django.

I am using django 2.1. I expected the following code to work, but it only returns the first part of what SQL server returns.

```py
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("sp_help testTable")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

I expected the output to be:

```
[('testTable', 'dbo', 'user table', datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 14, 16, 0, 46, 700000))]
[('testCol', 'varchar', 'no', '50', '', '', 'no', 'no', 'no', 'SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS')]
[...more result sets...]
```

Instead I got:

```
[('testTable', 'dbo', 'user table', datetime.datetime(2019, 10, 14, 16, 0, 46, 700000))]
```

Comment: You got the first result set returned from that procedure. I don't know anything about django but it is because there are multiple result sets returned, not multiple rows with varying numbers of columns.

Comment: Right. I would like to get all the result sets. It seems like fetchall() does the same thing as fetchone().

Comment: Not quite. fetchone() retrieves the next row from the active dataset, fetchall() retrieves all the rows from the active dataset. The procedure sp_help returns **multiple datasets**. Seems like this is the solution for dealing with this in python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273203/access-second-result-set-of-stored-procedure-with-sql-or-other-work-around-pyth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the guidance of Sean Lange, I figured out my problem was not django related. I needed to use: 'cursor.nextset()' to access the other result sets.

```
   cursor.nextset()
```